# Laravel auth middleware not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3, laravel-5.4

I have modularized my Laravel app. Following is the path where my controllers resides. 
`\app\Modules\Admin\Controllers\SettingController.php`

I am using Laravel default auth module for login. In the `SettingController` constructor I called `$this->middleware('auth');` , but even after I login to the app, it is redirecting to Laravel default home page. I think I am breaking some thing in Laravel's flow.

I have 2 route files. One is Laravel default route and another is custom one I created.

`\app\Modules\Admin\routes.php`

```
Route::group(['namespace' => 'App\Modules\Admin\Controllers'], function () {

  Route::get('admin/settings/stadium-level', 'SettingController@stadiumLevel');

});
```

Comment: Could you please your log under the storage folder?

Comment: Are you using different guards for these routes? Also, which routes file gets loaded first?

Comment: Have you added your both routes in RouteServiceProvider with namespace ?

Comment: Thank you guys for your hints, after adding web middleware Route::group(['middleware' => ['web'],'namespace' => 'App\Modules\Admin\Controllers'], it worked. (Y)

Answer (score 1):

you can use this code in your route option to specify your middleware explicitly

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    //
});
```